# jquery load Ajax - adding a click function to a class loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have been going round in circles with this. I am hoping someone can help.

I have been using this code to populate a div with images, each with a class="click"

```
$('#imagebox').load("../imagebox_builder.cshtml",{id:1});
```

I want to be able to add a hander to the images using the class of click as an identifier, to use load to populate another div with data. I am not sure how to add the click handler. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Delegate the event ..**

```
$('#imagebox').on('click', 'img.click', function(){
    console.log("Element with class click has been clicked");

    // Add the div here
});
```

Comment: we were typing nearly exactly the same thing at nearly exactly the same time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.on()` in its future tense to target dynamically created elements with the class `.click` that are created within something that exists (`#imagebox`)

```
$('#imagebox').on('click', '.click', function(e){
    // magic goes here
});
```